# How to convert to bytes format for PIL images which is similar to normal bytes format

Tags: python, image-processing

Sorry that I couldnt explain clearly in subject. 
I used read() to read the entire image in the form of bytes and also I used PIL's tobytes() to read the same image. But to me the image bytes looks different. Could you please advice on how to have the same bytes generated using read() using PIL's package utility? From raw encoding to utf-8

Code sample:

```
path3 = r'path'
with io.open(path3, 'rb') as image_file:
    content1 = image_file.read()
b'\xff\xd8\x ...
```

Using PIL:

```
with io.open(path3, 'rb') as image_file:
    content1 = Image.open(image_file).tobytes()
b'\xbf\x91\xc0\xbf\x91\xc0\xbe\x90\xbf\xbe'
```

In my use case:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_bytes
images = convert_from_bytes(open('pp.pdf', 'rb').read())
b=images[0].read() # since this returns list format
AttributeError: 'PpmImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Is it possible to have same byte format like read()?

Comment: Images don't use UTF-8. When you read as a file, you get the image dimensions, the camera model, the GPS location where it was shot, the copyright and all that suff. When you read the image using PIL, you get the decompressed pixels at each location in the image.

Comment: Is there anyway I can use the same bytes format? Because what happened is I have converted PDF to Image and this image is what I need to read.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand what you have done, or what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have just added an edit

Answer (score 0):

PIL is doing more than just reading the bytes of the image file. It is decompressing it from JPG or PNG or whatever format you are giving it. It's `tobytes` function returns all the pixel values.

In the first snippet you are simply reading in the bytes of the compressed image file. These will always be different unless you are using an uncompressed file format like [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).

Comment: I have just added an edit as per my use case.. My function is only accepting proper bytes format what read() does